# Output of Keras LSTMCell

Tags: tensorflow, keras, output, lstm, cell

I am implementing an LSTM cell using `tensorflow.keras.layers.LSTMCell` in order to optimize some parameters.

Over the different time steps of the recurrent network I want my input vector `x[t+1]` to be the output of the previous iteration at time step t. However, looking at the equations of the LSTMcell (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) and also to the source code of the `call()` method LSTMCell on Keras (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/rnn/lstm.py line 298), the output will be h, [h,c] being h the hidden state and c the cell state.

My question is how can I implement the LSTMCell on Keras so that on each iteration some inputs for the next step are output. One example of this could be made it's introducing antoher weights `Wp` and biases `bp` (appart from the ones that appears on equations of LSTM cells) that are trained so that `x[t+1] = Wp * ht + bp`. I have seen that this approach may be the one that uses the object `Model()` on Keras, but I am quite new on this and I don't know how it works.

Besides that, as a second question I would like to know why the output of the `call()` method for LSTM cell is `h, [h,c]`. What is the point on having `h` repeated twice there?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuVUA.png)

Thanks a lot everybody for your help,

To sum up, I need to find the predictions `yt` that appear on the link.